# Reading the first column of a csv with dictreader

Tags: python

I am trying to read several columns of a txt file and save them into a new file. Im always getting errors but only for the first column. If i exclude the first column it works perfectly fine. I spellchecked the column names.

My txt file looks like this:

```
trip_id,arrival_time,departure_time,stop_id,stop_sequence,stop_headsign,pickup_type,drop_off_type,shape_dist_traveled
"2.T0.2-577-j23-1.2.R","07:29:00","07:29:00","at:46:1888:0:1","1","","0","0","0.00"
"2.T0.2-577-j23-1.2.R","07:30:00","07:30:00","at:46:1885:0:1","2","","0","0","1732.64"
"2.T0.2-577-j23-1.2.R","07:31:00","07:31:00","at:46:1884:0:1","3","","0","0","2589.62"
```

and the part of the code that i cant get to work looks like this:

```py
def extract_and_save_columns(input_file, output_file, columns_to_keep):
    with open(input_file, "r", encoding='utf8') as source:
        reader = csv.DictReader(source)
        with open(output_file, "w", encoding='utf8', newline='') as result:
            fieldnames = columns_to_keep
            writer = csv.DictWriter(result, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()

            for row in reader:
                new_row = {col: row[col] for col in columns_to_keep}
                writer.writerow(new_row)

# Keep columns of stop_times.txt 
stop_times_columns_to_keep = ["trip_id", "arrival_time", "departure_time", "stop_sequence", "shape_dist_traveled"]
stop_times_input_file = path_to_gtfs + "stop_times.txt"
stop_times_output_file = path_to_gtfs + "stop_times_filtered.txt"


# Write new stop_times.txt
extract_and_save_columns(stop_times_input_file, stop_times_output_file, stop_times_columns_to_keep)
```

Traceback of the error i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\PycharmProjects\GTFS_ST&T\main.py", line 48, in <module>
    extract_and_save_columns(stop_times_input_file, stop_times_output_file, stop_times_columns_to_keep)
  File "...\PycharmProjects\GTFS_ST&T\main.py", line 29, in extract_and_save_columns
    new_row = {col: row[col] for col in columns_to_keep}
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\PycharmProjects\GTFS_ST&T\main.py", line 29, in <dictcomp>
    new_row = {col: row[col] for col in columns_to_keep}
                    ~~~^^^^^
KeyError: 'trip_id'
```

I basically want the output to look like this:

```
trip_id,arrival_time,departure_time,stop_sequence,shape_dist_traveled
"2.T0.2-577-j23-1.2.R","07:29:00","07:29:00","1","0.00"
"2.T0.2-577-j23-1.2.R","07:30:00","07:30:00","2","1732.64"
"2.T0.2-577-j23-1.2.R","07:31:00","07:31:00","3","2589.62"
```

Any idea of what i am doing wrong and how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: What do you get if you add `print(row)` before the line that raises the exception?

Comment: `{'\ufefftrip_id': '2.T0.2-577-j23-1.2.R', 'arrival_time': '07:29:00', 'departure_time': '07:29:00', ...}` is the output. Seems like the `\ufeff` is the problem there. Where does it come from and how do i get rid of it?

Comment: For the input file, replace `encoding='utf8'` by `encoding='utf_8_sig'`. The character is the so-called byte order mark used by the UTF encodings.